# UIScrollView + Zoom + Swipe

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, uiscrollview, touches

I need to make an UIScrollView recognize a swipe, but the problem is that the view is zoomed. So it won't work because of the bounces. Is there anyway to detect when the user has scrolled it to its limit?

Comment: If you don't want the bounce there are properties to turn the bounces off in a UIScrollView.

Comment: Then I cannot enable zoom. :(

Answer (score 0):

Read up on the scroll view delegate:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html

ScrollViewDidScroll will detect when a user has scrolled to the max or not.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to be the solution, however I haven't figured out how to detect how much it has scrolled.

Comment: What property can I use to check that user has scrolled to horizontal max for example? I see zoomBounce but not scrollBounce